# error 1045(28000) access denied for user 'tiennq' @ '172.17.0.1'

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, docker

I'm doing a project student management. Using docker to link with my sql
I've installed docker, and at the terminal, I type:

```
docker run -d --rm  --name mysql-spring-boot-tutorial -e MYSQL_USER=tiennq -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456 -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=123456 -e MYSQL_DATABASE=test_db -p 3309:3306 --volume mysql-spring-boot-tutorial-volume:/var/lib/mysql mysql:latest
```

and have succeeded create a container name "mysql spring boot tutorial"
but after that, I type

```
mysql -h localhost -P 3309 --protocol=tcp -u tiennq -p
```

I type password 123456 and then the system shows me: "access denied"
Is there anyone know how to solve this problem ?

[image: A screen shot showing the commands I typed and the resulting error]

Comment: I tried the commands from the post and I got the same error because it's trying to login to the local mysql server, not the mysql container.

Comment: @JoeS So how can I login to the mysql container ? should I delete the local mysql ?

Comment: you can login from within the container. Use `docker exec -ti <container name> bash` to get into the container's terminal, then run `mysql -u root -p`.  
If you want to login from your host's terminal, I suggest switching to the image `mysql:5.7`. I think the error happens on mysql:8+.